# How to convert UTC to EST or EDT in my sql

Tags: mysql, utc

I have created a table, which is given below,

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   department VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   submission_date DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

I have inserted data from user details table to user table. user details table contains utc date format in column `submission_date`.

Insertion query is given below,

```
INSERT INTO user
(name,department,submission_date)
SELECT name,department,submission_date FROM user_details;
```

How to convert utc to est/edt in my sql

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONVERT_TZ` to achieve this:

Note that -05:00 is for EST. You can modify this as per your need.

```
INSERT INTO user
(name,department,submission_date)
SELECT name,department,convert_tz(submission_date , '+00:00', '-05:00')
FROM user_details;
```

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=21d3552bd22aa618c4b9276ea0283dfe)

Comment: This is only correct for half the year, and doesn't consider dst

Comment: @Evert , Can you give solution for est?